# How can I make executables in my `PATH` available to GNU Make if they need to be run with sudo?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, makefile

Consider the following Makefile.

```
install:
    sudo rpi-install.py  /dev/ttyUSB0 foo.bin
```

Note that I have deliberately not hardcoded a path to `rpi-install.py` because it is not in the same location on other people's machines, but I expect it to be in the `PATH` of everyone who uses my code.

Unfortunately, when I type `make install`, I get the following output.

```
sudo rpi-install.py  /dev/ttyUSB0 larson.bin
sudo: rpi-install.py: command not found
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

When I type the **exact same command** on my shell, **it works exactly as expected**.

Additionally, when I remove the `sudo` from the Makefile, it successfully finds the binary and gets a permission denied error due to lack of root privileges.

**How can I allow `make` to discover the programs that are in my `PATH` when they must be run with `sudo`?**

---

For the sake of reproducibility, assume that the following contents are in `rpi-install.py`, and that it lives in the directory `$HOME/bin`. Additionally assume that `PATH` includes `$HOME/bin`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print "Hello World!"
```

Comment: This is dependent on the local `/etc/sudoers` file, which may or may not choose to honor the user's `PATH`.

Comment: ...though you can, of course, use `which` or similar to detect the location in the user's PATH, assign the fully-qualified path to a shell variable, and invoke *that* under `sudo`. Ick, but if you can't guarantee the local `sudoers` configuration...

Comment: @charlesduffy There is a special section in sudoers for the make shell that separates it from my normal bash?

Comment: Eh? No, it has nothing to do with `make` specifically, and everything to do with whether `PATH` is inherited or overridden.

Comment: I'm working under the assumption that the path is respected under my usual shell.  As described in my question the command,  sudo and all runs fine when invoked directly from the command line.

Comment: (btw, "the make shell" is `/bin/sh` by default).

Comment: `rpi-install.py` lives in *whose* `$HOME` directory? make running `sudo` and you running `sudo` shouldn't be meaningfully different I don't believe. Also interactive vs. non-interactive shell's might make a difference here. What adds `$HOME/bin` to the `$PATH` for that user?

Comment: BTW, why not just add yourself to the appropriate group so you don't need `sudo` to access the serial device?

Comment: @charlesduffy, because I can't ask the other users to all do that also. They prefer sudo.

Comment: My home directory not root. The path is set in bashrc. That may be the real issue.  I'll double check when I get back to computer.

Comment: Just throwing an idea that came into my mind while reading your question: `c=$(type -p something); sudo "$c"`

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein, unless memory fails me, `type` is a bashism -- I'm not certain it's guaranteed to be available in `/bin/sh`, as invoked by `make`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I believe `type` is mandated by POSIX.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy [type is indeed POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/type.html), though you're correct: -p isn't POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

There was a combination of two fixes that resolved this problem.

1. I needed to set `PATH` in `.profile` instead of `.bashrc` because the default shell `/bin/sh` used by `make` did not pick up the correct path from `.bashrc`.
2. I needed to set the environment for the `sudo` command inside the makefile explicitly to be the external PATH, based on this answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83191/how-to-make-sudo-preserve-path).

   ```
   sudo env "PATH=$(PATH)" rpi-install.py  /dev/ttyUSB0 larson.bin
   ```